# Why input stream cuts some characters from the second line of input

Tags: c++

I am coding a simple c++ program that reads from input a student surname followed by the midterm, final, and various homework grades (like this: Carlo 2 5 7 8).
The problem is that from the second line of input it cuts some of the student surname.

One example.

```
Enter the surname of each student followed by the midterm, final, and homework grades.
Carlo 2 3 4 5
Bonandrini 2 3 4 5

Carlo     3.4
onandrini 3.4
```

As you can see the second name missed a b at the front.
I've tried different names and lengths of names but nothing changes, it still cuts the name.
From what I understand the problem comes from getting the input itself.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<ios>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdexcept>

template<typename T>
T median(std::vector<T> vec) // Not passed by name because we sort the vector
{
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = vec.size();

    if(!size)
        throw std::domain_error("Median of an empty vector");

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    vec_sz pos = size / 2;

    return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[pos] + vec[pos-1]) / 2 : vec[pos];
}

template<typename T>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    if(stream) // If stream is actually open
    {
        vec.clear(); // In case the vector wasn't empty

        T x; 
        while(stream >> x)
            vec.push_back(x);


        stream.clear();
    }
    return stream;
}

struct StudentInfo
{
    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
};

double grade(const StudentInfo& student)
{
    return 0.2 * student.midterm + 0.4 * student.final + 0.4 * median<double>(student.homework);
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, StudentInfo& student)
{
    stream >> student.name >> student.midterm >> student.final;

    stream >> student.homework;

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the surname of each student followed by the midterm, final, and homework grades" << std::endl;
    std::vector<StudentInfo> students;

    std::string::size_type maxlen = 0;
    StudentInfo student;
    while(std::cin >> student) 
    {
       maxlen = std::max(maxlen, student.name.size());
        students.push_back(student);
    }

    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), 
    [](const StudentInfo& student1, const StudentInfo& student2){ return student1.name < student2.name; });

    for(StudentInfo student : students)
    {
        // + 1 to put a space between the name and the grade
        std::cout << student.name << std::string(maxlen + 1 - student.name.size(), ' ');

        try{
            double points = grade(student);
            std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
            std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << points << std::setprecision(prec);
        }
        catch(std::domain_error e){
            std::cout << e.what();
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program should output the list of students with the appropriate grade.

Comment: Can you narrow down the source of error at all? Can you provide a test case where this error fails? A [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would be ideal since it's a bit of code

Comment: What do you mean by name? Like First Last?

Comment: It is unclear what is actually on the "second line of input". What is on the first line of input? What does each line actually look like? Which characters are being "cut off" exactly? In your example, `Carlos 2 5 7 8` is missing a `< 0` value at the end to tell your `operator>>` to stop looping. Also, having your `operator>>` call `stream.clear()` after reading input is wrong, don't do that. That prevents the caller from detecting stream errors correctly.

Comment: This appears to work for me. I would have used getline, though, and parsed it from the stringstream. Odd that you have a custom operator>> but not operator<<. And you could define operator< so the sort works without a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by name, you mean "First Last" or "Last, First" or something like that.

If that is the case, the problem is with your use of std::stream >> std::string. This input deliminates on a space. Anything after the space is considered a new string, unless you tell it. If midterm were a string not a double, the part after the space would show up there. Instead, it just ignores it because it doesn't know how to turn it into a string.

What you need is std::stream.getline() that will probably do the trick.

Comment: by name i mean only the surname so that is not the problem.

Comment: Okay. Well, in that case, can you give a test case, expected results, and actual results?

Comment: I have put it at the beginning of the question

Comment: @CarloBonandrini I can't reproduce the problem. The only thing I did different is I controlled the loop like this:  for(unsigned int i=0;i<students.size();i++)
    {
  StudentInfo student = students[i];
Instead of your way because I have an older C++ and it works fine.

Comment: what Are you using to end the input? I’m using end-of-Line command in macos that is ctrl+d.